# CSS: change multiple image position when hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have one large image on the top and three smaller images on the bottom of my page. I want to make it so when you hover the small image (it's also a link which goes to different place) the large image changes to this small image. So clearly explained, two images change/swap places. And when I unhover the large image changes back. I tried a couple solution but it didn't work so I'm in trouble, can you please help me?

I'm looking for CSS/Javascript-solution **NOT JQUERY!**

Thanks and sorry for bothering!

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../screens/StyleName.css";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Categories from "../components/Categories.json";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

// images:
import LargeImage from "../images/largeimage.jpg;
import SmallImage1 from "../images/small_image1.jpg";
import SmallImage2 from "../images/small_image2.jpg";
import SmallImage3 from "../images/small_image3.jpg";
import Placeholder from "../images/placeholder.jpg";

function FunctionName() {

  let location = useLocation();

  const ShowImage = (ImageName) => {
    if (ImageName === "SmallImage1") {
      return SmallImage1;
    } else if (ImageName === "SmallImage2") {
      return SmallImage2;
    } else if (ImageName === "SmallImage3") {
      return SmallImage3;
    } else {
      return Placeholder;
    }
  };

  const AllCategories = () => {
    return Categories.map((category, index) => {
      const data = () => {
        if (category.children) {
          return { data: category.children };
        } else {
          return { data: undefined };
        }
      };
      return (
        <div key={index} className="category-card">
          <Card style={{ border: "none" }}>
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: location.pathname + "/" + category.name,
                state: data(),
              }}
              className="category-link link"
            >
              <div className="img__wrap">
                <Card.Img
                  variant="top"
                  alt="card-img-top"
                  className="small-img-down img-responsive img__img"
                  src={ShowImage(category.name)}
                />
                <p className="img__description">{category.name}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="maincategory-top">
      <div className="category-container">
        <div className="col-sm-8">
          <Link to="/product" className="category-link link">
            <Card.Img
              alt="card-img-top"
              className="big-img img-responsive"
              src={LargeImage}
            />
          </Link>
          <div className="row">{AllCategories()}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FunctionName;
```

CSS:

```css
.big-img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 470px;
  height: 300px;
}
.category-container {
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.card-title-main {
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.category-link:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.category-link:visited {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.category-link:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.category-link:active {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.category2 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}
.small-img-down {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.small-img-down:hover {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.category-card {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.363);
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, visibility 0.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
() => {
const default_large = "image_one"
const [largeImage, setLargeImage] = useState(default_large);
     return(
        <div>
          <img 
           src={image_one} 
           onMouseEnter={() => setLargeImage("image_one")}
           onMouseOut={() => setLargeImage(default_large)} 
           className={largeImage === "image_one" ? "large" : "small"}
          />
        <img 
           src={image_two} 
           onMouseEnter={() => setLargeImage("image_two")}
           onMouseOut={() => setLargeImage(default_large)} 
           className={largeImage === "image_two" ? "large" : "small"}
          />
         <img 
           src={image_three} 
           onMouseEnter={() => setLargeImage("image_three")}
           onMouseOut={() => setLargeImage(default_large)} 
           className={largeImage === "image_three" ? "large" : "small"}
          />
        </div>
     )
}
```

In your css.

```css
img.large{
     width: 500px
}

img.small{
     width: 100px
}
```

**Explanation:**
Keep track of what image is large in your component state. Whenever an image is hovered on, update the state accordingly. After the hover event, return the state to its default state. The image will have the "large" class while its being hovered on, and when no image is being hovered on, the default large image will be large.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! I tried your solution and I came across a problem. I have those category names on my REST API which those images are based. Now it shows all the small images big when I place the cursor over the big image. So it renders all images in it. The big image is not mapped only the small ones. What should  I do? Did I do something wrong? Many thanks again! x

Comment: If all your small images get big when you hover over the big image then that means your "if statements" are off.. Your "if statements" are returning true for every image.

Comment: Okay now it shows the small image correctly (i.e. it enlarges when you put the hover over the image) but it doesn't replace it to the default large image but enlarges in its own place.. I have no idea what is the problem here.

Comment: The large image staying large regardless of the state indicates it's either not respecting its css rules or, the if() statement that determines whether or not it should be large, is always true.